# Unable To Upload To Google Cloud Bucket via Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

keystore.load(r.openRawResource(R.raw.key),
        "password".toCharArray());

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("privatekey", "password".toCharArray());

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(STORAGE_SCOPE))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
        //.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/storage/sdcard0/key.p12"))

        .build();
```

> W/System.err﹕ PKCS12 key store mac invalid - wrong password or corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a private key that you downloaded from your Developer Console Credentials page?

This is how I am connecting to my Google Cloud Bucket:
[Android GoogleCredential Debug vs Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384643/android-googlecredential-debug-vs-release)